# Importing Text File in Android Application?

Tags: android, file

I've been getting the following error when I attempt to run an android application that inputs data from a text file.
"java.io.fileNotFoundException: /File.txt: open failed:ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

The file in question is in the Eclipse project folder.
I also tried putting it in the assets folder as well as several others.
Here is the code in question:

```
File file = new File("File.txt");
    TestOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
    String x = "";
    try
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            x = sc.nextLine();
            TestOutput.add(x);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So far I have attempted to use a wrapper class to no avail, the code of which is below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FileGet
{

ArrayList<String> TestOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
public FileGet() {

}
public ArrayList<String> getFile() {
    File file = new File("TestOutput.txt");
    TestOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String x = "";
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            x = scanner.nextLine();
            TestOutput.add(x);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return TestOutput;
}
}
```

That code works fine outside of the android application. Any advice/responses would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put the file into assets and then use that file using asset manager. You can then open inputstream to that file to read.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an example of using the asset manager that I could read?

Comment: You can easily search that on google just type 'read text file from assets android'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the string named "line" is the string where all the TextFile is read.

Put the .txt file under /resources/raw folder.

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.name_of_file);
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
try {
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
    total.append(line);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
line = total.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The input stream has a `copyTo` method with a default buffer size.

```
    suspend fun copyFile(src: Uri, dest: Uri) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        contentResolver.openInputStream(src)?.use { inputStream ->
            contentResolver.openOutputStream(dest)?.use { outputStream ->
                inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public fun InputStream.copyTo(out: OutputStream, bufferSize: Int = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE): Long {
    var bytesCopied: Long = 0
    val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
    var bytes = read(buffer)
    while (bytes >= 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytes)
        bytesCopied += bytes
        bytes = read(buffer)
    }
    return bytesCopied
}
```